# pandas way to turn DataFrame of sets into DataFrame of dictionaries with value in corresponding cell in other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

It's hard to explain what I'm trying to do so I'll give an example. In the example below, I am trying to get `df3`. I have done it with the code below but it is very "anti-pandas" and I am looking for a better (faster, cleaner, more pandas-esque) way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"begin": [{"a", "b"}, {"b"}, {"c"}], "end": [{"x"}, {"z", "y"}, {"z"}]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [10, 10, 15], "b": [15, 20, 30], "c": [8, 12, 10], "x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [1, 3, 4], "z": [1, 3, 1]}
)

df3 = df1.copy()

for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df1.loc[i])):
        df3.at[i, df1.columns[j]] = []
        for v in df1.loc[i][j]:
            df3.at[i, df1.columns[j]].append({"letter": v, "value": df2.loc[i][v]})


print(df3)
```

Here's my goal (which this code does, just probably not in the best way):

```
                                 begin                                                end
0  [{'letter': 'b', 'value': 15}, {'letter': 'a', 'value': 10}        [{'letter': 'x', 'value': 1}]
1  [{'letter': 'b', 'value': 20}]                                     [{'letter': 'y', 'value': 3}, {'letter': 'z', 'value': 3}
2 [{'letter': 'c', 'value': 10}]                                      [{'letter': 'z', 'value': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the problem using `pandas`

```
# Reshape and explode the dataframe
s = df1.stack().explode().reset_index(name='letter')

# Map the values corresponding to the letters
s['value'] = s.set_index(['level_0', 'letter']).index.map(df2.stack())

# Assign list of records
s['records'] = s[['letter', 'value']].to_dict('records')

# Pivot with aggfunc as list
s = s.pivot_table('records', 'level_0', 'level_1', aggfunc=list)
```

---

```
print(s)

level_1                                                         begin                                                         end
level_0                                                                                                                          
0        [{'letter': 'a', 'value': 10}, {'letter': 'b', 'value': 15}]                               [{'letter': 'x', 'value': 1}]
1                                      [{'letter': 'b', 'value': 20}]  [{'letter': 'z', 'value': 3}, {'letter': 'y', 'value': 3}]
2                                      [{'letter': 'c', 'value': 10}]                               [{'letter': 'z', 'value': 1}]
```